# ¿Cómo dar el tamaño a un array en una función después de inicializarlo?

Tags: java, pilas

Tengo que declarar un array *Pila* con valor nulo y agregarle el tamaño 10 cuando se use la función `crear_pila` pero me da error.

Código:

```
public static int crear_pila(pila[]) {
    pila[] = new int [10];
    return pila;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int pila[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno ese código no te funcionará y explico el porque:

Primero que no especificas el tipo de dato en el parámetro y aunque lo especificaras me parece que está por demás por el hecho de que no necesitas usar la misma variable si retornaras una totalmente nueva.

```
public static int crear_pila(int[] pila) { // En todo caso debería ser de la siguiente forma:
```

Y segundo, veo que tu función retorna un array de enteros `int[]` por lo tanto debes especificarlo:

```
public static int[] crear_pila(int[] pila) {
```

Ahora bien yo te recomendaria utilizar lo siguiente declarando una variable global o simplemente crear tu función solamente para instanciar el array, dejo ambos ejemplos abajo:

Función con variable global:

```
private static int pila[] = null;
public static int[] crear_pila() {
    pila = new int[10];
    return pila;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // int pila[]; // Esto ya no seria necesario
    crear_pila();
}
```

Función con método para instanciar:

```
public static int[] crear_pila() {
    return new int [10];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int pila[] = crear_pila();
}
```

Espero te sirva ;)

Answer (score 2):

me figuro que eres nuevo en java, te paso la solución comentada para que lo entiendas :)

```
/*Nomenclatura de métodos y atributos, siempre usa formato camelCase 
no barra bajas para nombrar tus funciones y atributos java. 
Estándares de java: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html*/
/*
Public indica que el método es público, es decir, de visibilidad total.
static indica que se debe llamar de manera estática
int[] es el tipo de dato que va a devolver la función, ¿¿es una pila de ints no?? NOTA: en java llamalos mejor Arrays, o listas, no son pilas, es un error de concepto.
crearPila es el nombre del metodo
() todos los parámetros de entrada de la función.
*/
public static int[] crearPila(int tamanioPila)// parámetros, siempre el tipo de parámetro y el nombre del parámetro
{
    //retornamos una pila con el tamanio de la pila que quieres pasarle como parámetro.
    return new int[tamanioPila];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //llamamos a la función de crearPila para que cree una pila con tamanio 10, y se la asignamos el retorno de esa función a una variable del mismo tipo
    int[] pilaFinal= crearPila(10);
}
```

P.D.:Si quieres saber cual es la diferencia entre lista y pila añade un comentario, te responderé encantado

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo mi solución:

```
  public static int[] crear_pila() {
    return new int [10];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int pila[] = null;

    pila = crear_pila();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te lanza **excepciones** porque:

1. Te falto decirle al compilador que tipo de dato sera tu array.
2. No le estas pasando ningun parametro a tu metodo crear_pila().
3. No estas llamando correctamente al metodo crear_pila() en el metodo main.
4. No le estas diciendo a crear_pila() que devuelva un array.
5. No le estas diciendo a crear_pila que identificador usar para la variable que le vas a pasar por parametro.

Primero tienes que decirle a crear_pila que devolvera un array, eso se hace en la declaracion del metodo, despues de **int** tienes que poner unos corchetes, No es necesario que le pases parametros a tu método (los parametros se pasan por los parentesis de los metodos) ya que el tamaño siempre sera 10 como escribiste, el método quedaria así.

```
    public static int[] crear_pila() {
    int pila[] = new int [10];
    return pila;
}
```

Tú método es **estatico** (static) significa que para llamarlo tienes que usar la misma clase, y eso se hace escribiendo el nombre de la clase seguido de un punto y después el nombre del método, es decir:

```
MyClass.crear_pila();
```

Todo el código quedaria así:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        

    MyClass.crear_pila();


    }

    public static int[] crear_pila() {
    int pila[] = new int [10];
    return pila;
}

}
```

Existen varias convenciones para programar en Java, una de esas es que el nombre de los metodos usan lowerCameCase, es decir la primera palabra siempre comenzara por minúscula y si tu método tiene varias palabras, la segunda palabra comenzara por mayúscula, es decir que quedaria asi.

- Una palabra

  public static int[] crear()
- Dos palabras

  public static int[] crearPila()